# How to avoid full app reloading on onSubmit action in form?

Tags: reactjs, performance

Whenever user submit search form, user get redirected to search page and the searching works fine but the problem is: my app reloads completely, all my app disappears for a while, weakens the speed of my app (By doing many unwanted operations). Also, it causes for a few other bugs which make my app look ugly. So, how do I avoid the full app reloading when I do searching?

The perfect example is the [Walmart](https://www.walmart.com/) website. Try to search something there, the header doesn't disappear like my one does.

I have tried with e.preventDefault() but my searcher doesn't work then..

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: e.preventDefault() simply prevents reloading but I'm not sure if it prevents something else which must also work behind the scenes.

Comment: My searching doesn't work then. Thanks!

Comment: Please post code instead of screenshot. Also explain your search more to get a precise answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`evt.preventDefault()` stops the form submission & hence the page reloading. Now you have to make an AJAX/`fetch` call to the `/search` endpoint. Something like:

```
handleSubmit=async (evt)=> {
    evt.preventDefault();
    var res = await fetch('/search/',{method:'POST', body:JSON.stringify(...));
    res = await res.text();
    setResult(res);
}
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch